# Meaning of "-4init/0hard/0soft" for value in optaplanner result?

Tags: jboss, optaplanner

I have been doing the demos for optaplanner. They have been great. I have been playing around with them, but I have gotten stuck on figuring out what this result is.

I followed this tutorial [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-docs/blob/master/docs/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/src/main/asciidoc/Workbench/Quickstart/Quickstart-section.adoc#submit-solution). Basically, its the cloud balancing example with multiple rules. When I set the any value of an attribute of a processes (memory, cpu or bandwidth) high (over 20), and ping the optaplanner server. It does not solve it, returns "-4init/0hard/0soft". I understand what the hard and soft scores are, but not the init. Once I reduce the value of attribute, it solve it normally.

If anyone knows about where to learn more on the optaplanner docs, I would appreciate it!

Result of GET on status of solver

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-4init` means that 4 planning variables were not initialized. This probably means that the Construction Heuristic didn't have enough time to finish. Possible fixes:

- Give the solver more time (if acceptable)
- Increase the score calculation speed by implementing the score constraints more efficiently (if possible)
- Look at the docs "scaling construction heuristics" to power tweak them to be faster (if it's a scaling issue)
- Use faster hardware (if it's NOT a scaling issue)

**Use optaplanner-benchmark** with multiple datasets in different sizes to get more insight as to what is the best path forward.